# jQuery addClass to multiple elements shows an unexpected delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm making a flipping counter which is supposed to change color when reaching the target number (1000 in the example). But the thing is the different parts of the counter doesn't change color at the same time, we can clearly see a delay between the tiles that make up the counter...

I'm using a simple jQuery addClass to trigger the color change:

```
$("#rhcounter .count").addClass("red");
```

Any ideas what could be causing that ?

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ka6ke28m/6/

Thanks for your help !

Comment: For starters it does not help that you keep calling the same jQUery selector over and over instead of saving the first result in a var and using that :)

Comment: I haven't figured out the actual problem based on your description, but here is a much faster version to play with: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/ka6ke28m/5/

Comment: thanks for your example, it does look cleaner but it seems to be bugging though, i'll look into it

Comment: Where is "red" class. Is this in .css?

Comment: My previous fiddle reversed the order as I did not spot you had tile3,2,1 & 0 in reverse order in the HTML. I fixed that and a few other issues below. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### First issue:

There was a huge amount of wasted processing going on. jQuery selectors have an overhead so reduce them to a minimum and complex selectors more-so. I have reduced that considerably.

### Second issue:

There is a nasty visual glitch on some browsers that looked like this:

[image]

Which you can eliminate by using `background-color:` instead of `background:` (which tries to completely re-render the area instead of just fill the background colour).

### Third issue:

The color blue left behind was down to slow repainting of the screen. The above two fixes had a huge impact and I also tried adding specific CSS animations that worked only with the red class. This can probably be improved now you know the causes of the slow painting (e.g. have blue and red CSS animation?):

http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/ka6ke28m/10/

```
$(function () {
    var total = 1000,
        current = 950,
        timeout = 150,
        inc = 7,
        prevTiles = ["0", "0", "0", "0"],
        interval = setInterval(function () {
            increase()
        }, timeout),
        increase = function () {
            current += inc;

            if (current >= total) {
                clearInterval(interval);
                current = total;
            }

            if (current === total) {
                $("#rhcounter .count").addClass("red");
            }
            // instant timer to delay css
            setTimeout(function () {
                var tiles = [false, false, false, false],
                    currStr = (current + "").split("").reverse().join("");

                for (var i = 0; i < currStr.length; i++) {
                    if (currStr[i] !== prevTiles[i]) {
                        tiles[i] = true;
                        prevTiles[i] = currStr[i];
                    }
                }

                tiles.forEach(function (tile, index) {
                    if (!tile) {
                        return;
                    }

                    // Get the current tile
                    var $tile = $("#rhcounter div.tile" + index);
                    $tile.children('span.curr').each(function () {
                        $(this).text($tile.text());
                    });
                    $tile.removeClass("flip");
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $tile.addClass("flip");
                    }, 5);

                    var top = $tile.find("span.count.next.top"),
                        bottom = $tile.find("span.count.next.bottom"),
                        delay = (index === 0 ? timeout : 250);

                    setTimeout(function () {
                        top.text(prevTiles[index]);
                    }, delay / 2);
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        bottom.text(prevTiles[index]);
                    }, delay / 2);
                });
            }, 1);
        };
});
```

Comment: 1st and 2nd issues resulted from coding too fast, thanks for the improvement, it's appreciated :) However it still have the delay issue despite the better perfs. Also it'd seem like `$tile.text()` line 41 doesn't always return the correct value which result into "00" being displayed on the tile, any idea what could be causing that?

Answer (score 0):

that was happening because you were changing color before changing text. i just shifted if condition and i think that is what you wanted [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ka6ke28m/1/)

```
$(window).load(function() {
    var total = 1000, current = 950, timeout = 150, inc = 7,
        prevTiles = ["0","0","0","0"],
        interval = setInterval(function(){increase()}, timeout),
        increase = function () {
            current += inc;

            if (current >= total) { 
                clearInterval(interval);
                current = total;
            }



            var tiles = [false, false, false, false], 
                currStr = (current+"").split("").reverse().join("");

            for (var i = 0; i < currStr.length; i++) {
                if (currStr[i] !== prevTiles[i]) { 
                    tiles[i] = true; 
                    prevTiles[i] = currStr[i];
                }
            }

            tiles.forEach(function (tile, index) {
                if (!tile) { return; }

                $("#rhcounter > div[class~='tile"+index+"'] > span[class~='curr']").each(function() {
                    $(this).text($("#rhcounter > div[class~='tile"+index+"'] > span.count.next.top").text());
                });
                $("#rhcounter > div[class~='tile"+index+"']").removeClass("flip");
                setTimeout(function(){$("#rhcounter > div[class~='tile"+index+"']").addClass("flip");}, 5);

                var top = $("#rhcounter > div[class~='tile"+index+"'] > span.count.next.top"),
                    bottom = $("#rhcounter > div[class~='tile"+index+"'] > span.count.next.bottom"),
                    delay = (index === 0 ? timeout : 250);

                setTimeout(function(){ top.text(prevTiles[index]); }, delay/2);
                setTimeout(function(){ bottom.text(prevTiles[index]); }, delay/2);
            });
         if (current === total) { 
                $("#rhcounter .count").addClass("red");
            }};
});
```

Comment: My screen still goes nuts on that sample when it starts. Really weird black pixels everywhere :(

Comment: may be problem of browser

Comment: Still trying to make out the actual problem in their sample, but how would moving the `addClass("red")` change anything (as most of the work is being done asynchronously after that code runs)?

Comment: thanks for your help but I still see the issue with your example

Comment: The black pixels were down to using CSS `background:` instead of `background-color:`. I added a screenshot to my answer so you can see what happens. :)